# JQuery function stops working when moved to js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been developing my scripts in line and now want to start moving them to a js file. However, the first script I am moving will not work from the js file.

```
function listEvents(url, phash) {
    var hashlocation = phash.split('#')[1];
    if (hashlocation === undefined) {
        var page = '';
    } else {
        var page = hashlocation;
    }
    $('#events').empty().load(url + page);
}
```

Called from page like so;

```
$(window).load(function() {
    listEvents('<? echo base_url(); ?>ajax/events_ajax/',window.location.hash);
});
```

The js file is loaded after the jquery library in the head before anyone asks. I have cleared my cache, put cloudflare into dev mode etc, and if I load the JS file in my browser I see my function. I'm not seeing any errors in the console. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you would need to put your code into `.ready` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).load(function() {
      listEvents('<? echo base_url(); ?>ajax/events_ajax/',window.location.hash);
   });
});
```

#### Explanation:

The problem is that when you fired your code, the content has not fully been loaded, which in your case, I think is `#events`. It was not on the ***[DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html)*** yet and as a result ignored by jQuery. If you run it in you HTML file, most like you'd put your code right under `<div id="events"></div>` (or whatever your container is) and because it was executed afterwards, that element was found and your code worked expected way!

Read more about [jQuery .ready() function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

- `.ready()` *function:* Specify a function to execute when the ***[DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html)*** is fully loaded.

Comment: Yes this was the problem, but it was working inline, so can you please explain why it had to be wrapped in '$(document).ready(function(){});' to make it work from external file so that I can understand this for the future. Thanks.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev why not just get rid of the `$(window).load` altogether in favor of `$(document).ready`?

Comment: Thank you Ilia for the explanation.

Comment: @zamnuts There are bunch of other ways for achieving desired results!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your embedded PHP `<? echo base_url(); ?>`:

```
listEvents('<? echo base_url(); ?>ajax/events_ajax/',window.location.hash);
```

Check your **network** panel in your browser's dev tools, not just console. See if you're seeing any 404s.

If you were working with inline scripts, those are PHP, but after moving to a `.js` file, the files are no longer handled by PHP.

Comment: No the php is not in the js file. It's in the page file.

Comment: @Ally, oops yea, missed that detail in your post "Called from page like so"